# Fast array permutation (generalised tensor transpose) in Armadillo (C++)

Tags: c++, permutation, rcpp, transpose, armadillo

I have a project which involves a lot of permutations on 3D arrays ( `arma::Cube<cx_double>`). In particular, the required permutation is the interchange of columns by slices. In Matlab this is efficiently calculated by `permute(cube,[1,3,2])` and in Python by `numpy.transpose(cube,axis=[0,2,1])`.

Unfortunately Armadillo doesn't have a `permute` function on its own. I have tried different approaches but all of them rather slow when compared to Matlab. **I would like to know what's the faster way to permute (rather large) Cubes in Armadillo**. Profiling the code with `gprof`, most of the time is spent in the permute functions that I have tried below, whereas in Matlab, for the same ported project, most of the time is spent in SVD or QR matrix decompositions (reshape and permute are fast in matlab).

I would like to understand which is the fastest way to do this permutation in Armadillo and why some approaches work better than others.

**Option 1: Raw permutation** (Fastest option) (Is there a faster approach?)

Element-wise assignment of input cube to output cube.

```
template <typename T>
static Cube<T> permute (Cube<T>& cube){

uword D1=cube.n_rows;
uword D2=cube.n_cols;
uword D3=cube.n_slices;

Cube<T> output(D1,D3,D2);

for (uword s = 0; s < D3; ++s){
for (uword c = 0; c < D2; ++c){
for (uword r = 0; r < D1; ++r){
    output.at(r, s, c) = cube.at(r, c, s);
    // output[ D1*D3*c + D1*s+ r ] = cube[ D1*D2*s + D1*c + r ]; 

}
}
}

return output;
}
```

**Option 2: Filling slices**  (Very slow)

Fill the slices of the output cube by non-contiguous `subcube` views.

```
template <typename T>
static Cube<T> permute (Cube<T>& cube_in){

    uword D1 = cube_in.n_rows;
    uword D2 = cube_in.n_cols;
    uword D3 = cube_in.n_slices;

    Cube<T> output; 
    output.zeros(D1, D3, D2);

    for (uword c=0; c<D2; ++c) {
        output.slice(c) = cube_in.subcube( span(0,D1-1),span(c),span(0,D3-1) );
    }

    return output;
}
```

**Option 3: Transposing layers** (slower than Raw permutation but comparable)

We can iterate over layers (fixed row) of the input cube and transpose them.

```
template <typename T>
static Cube<T> permute (Cube<T>& cube_in){
    // in a cube, permute {1,3,2} (permute slices by columns)

    uword D1 = cube_in.n_rows;
    uword D2 = cube_in.n_cols;
    uword D3 = cube_in.n_slices;

    if(D3 > D2){
        cube_in.resize(D1,D3,D3);
    } else if (D2 > D3) {
        cube_in.resize(D1,D2,D2);
    }

    for (uword r=0; r<D1; ++r) {        
        static cmat layer = cmat(cube_in.rows(r,r)); 
        inplace_strans(layer);
        cube_in.rows(r,r)=layer;               
    }

    cube_in.resize(D1,D3,D2);

    return cube_in;
}
```

**Option 4: Look-up table**
Get non-contiguous access by reading indeces in a vector.

```
template <typename T>
arma::Cube<T> permuteCS (arma::Cube<T> cube_in){
    // in a cube, permute {1,3,2} (permute slices by columns)
    uword D1 = cube_in.n_rows;
    uword D2 = cube_in.n_cols;
    uword D3 = cube_in.n_slices;

    cx_vec onedcube = cube_in.elem(gen_trans_idx(cube_in));            

    return arma::Cube<T>(onedcube.memptr(), D1, D3, D2, true ) ;
}
```

where `gen_trans_idx` is a function that generates the indeces of the permuted cube:

```
template <typename T>
uvec gen_trans_idx(Cube<T>& cube){

    uword D1 = cube.n_rows;
    uword D2 = cube.n_cols;
    uword D3 = cube.n_slices;

    uvec perm132(D1*D2*D3);    
    uword ii = 0;                
    for (int c = 0; c < D2; ++c){
    for (int s = 0; s < D3; ++s){
    for (int r = 0; r < D1; ++r){
        perm132.at(ii) = sub2ind(size(cube), r, c, s);
        ii=ii+1;
    }}} 

    return perm132;
}
```

Ideally, one would pre-calculate these look-up tables if the Cube dimensions are determined beforehand.

**Option 5** (in-place transposition) Very slow, memory efficient

```
// Option: In-place transpose
template <typename T>
arma::Cube<T> permuteCS (arma::Cube<T> cube_in, uvec permlist ){    

    T* Qpoint = cube_in.memptr(); // pointer to first element of cube_in

    uvec updateidx = find(permlist - arma::linspace<uvec>(0,cube_in.n_elem-1,cube_in.n_elem)); // index of elements that change position in memory           
    uvec skiplist(updateidx.n_elem,fill::zeros);

    uword rr = 0; // aux index for updatelix
    for(uword jj=0;jj<updateidx.n_elem;++jj){                

        if(any(updateidx[jj] == skiplist)){ // if element jj has already been updated
            // do nothing
        } else {

            uword scope = updateidx[jj];
            T target = *(Qpoint+permlist[scope]);        // store the value of the target element             

            while(any(scope==skiplist)-1){              // while wareyou has not been updated

                T local  = *(Qpoint+scope);                  // store local value                                                                
                *(Qpoint+scope) = target;       
                skiplist[rr]=scope;
                ++rr;            
                uvec wareyou = find(permlist==scope);        // find where the local value will appear                
                scope = wareyou[0];
                target = local;                            
            }

        }
    }
   cube_in.reshape(cube_in.n_rows,cube_in.n_slices,cube_in.n_cols);

    return cub

e_in;
}
```

Comment: I think `.t` or `.st` transposes a amadrillo matix. http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Comment: `.t`or `.st` are methods of arma::Mat not arma::Cube

Comment: Interesting question,  but why the [tag:rcpp] tag?

Comment: I've been told that RcppArmadillo users deal with Cubes on a constant basis and maybe I can get some insight from their experience.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796248/armadillo-equivalent-of-matlab-permute

Comment: the answer to the question referred by @mtall is essentially a raw permutation (Option 1 above). I am wondering about the fastest strategy to do this permutation.

Comment: At the first blush you can optimize it by doing `Cube<T> output(D1, D3, D2);` instead of `Cube<T> output; output.zeros(D1, D3, D2);`, because you actually don't need to initialize memory. Also you can try to do a hack using `memcpy` and the fact that all the data is stored contigously (http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube). Of course, that won't be safe and will be platform dependent, but should be a lot more faster. Another idea is to create your wrapper with extra boolean field for transposed / not transposed, and override methods, like indexing

Comment: Hi @CrafterKolyan, you are right about the initialisation of `output` (I edited my answer). Regarding the alternative using `memcpy`, I am not sure how would I implement this option. In option 4, I access the element non-contiguously in a vector and construct a new Cube using a pointer to this vector. Could you maybe develop your comment into an answer? Many thanks

Comment: @cacosomoza I will try to think about this only on evening. Also I looked a little bit through your code, and want you to add `const reference` where possible to prevent copying objects. E.g.: `arma::Cube<T> permuteCS (const arma::Cube<T> &cube_in, const uvec &permlist)`. Also i think you'll need to do your tests again, because this might affect your speed greatly if `D1 * D2 * D3` is large. And I have a question: do you always need a `new Cube<T>` or maybe we can modify `Cube<T>` in parameter of function and not create a new instance each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code goes as addition to my commentary about `memcpy` hack. Also don't forget to try to add `const reference` to prevent copying objects.

```
template <typename T>
static Cube<T> permute(const Cube<T> &cube){
    const uword D1 = cube.n_rows;
    const uword D2 = cube.n_cols;
    const uword D3 = cube.n_slices;
    const uword D1_mul_D3 = D1 * D3;
    const Cube<T> output(D1, D3, D2);

    const T * from = cube.memptr();
    T *to = output.memptr();

    for (uword s = 0; s < D3; ++s){
        T *to_tmp = to + D1 * s;
        for (uword c = 0; c < D2; ++c){
            memcpy(to_tmp, from, D1 * sizeof(*from));
            from += D1;
            to_tmp += D1_mul_D3;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```